# jquery mobile with visualforce. Date picker not rendering correctly

Tags: visualforce, mobile

I have a VF page which has couple of date fields and i am using jquery mobile. The date picker doesnt seems to be rendering correctly. The month and year seem to be in jan and year 2013 by default even though the selected value is dfferent. When we click on the drop down of month the month of April is correctly selected but is not shown correctly. The formatting also seems to be off. Has anyone implemented the Datepicker using jquery mobile?

Any tips or thoughts regarding this would be helpful

[image]

Its a simple VF code to using apex:inputfield for close date on opportunity. Its taking the default css of jquery mobile. Is there some way to make apex:input field not use querymobiles css?

In the code i am allowing input of fields which are part of a fieldset

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>


<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Phone_Resource,'smartphone/css/style.css')}"/>  
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Phone_Resource,'smartphone/css/vfstyle.css')}"/> 

  <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
 <script type="application/x-javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").each(function(){
          $(this).attr("rel","external");
    });


}); 
</script> 
<body data-role="page" data-theme="b">
    <div class="wrap" data-role="header" data-theme="b">     
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header_top">
                <div class="menu-ico"><a href="#menu"></a></div>
                <div class="profile_details">
                               <div id="loginContainer">
                                  <a id="loginButton" class=""><span>Logout</span></a>   
                                    <!-- <div id="loginBox">                
                                      <form id="loginForm">
                                        <fieldset id="body">
                                            <div class="user-info">
                                                <ul>

                                                    <li class="logout"><a href="#"> Logout</a></li>

                                                </ul><div class="clear"></div>

                                            </div>                                      
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </form>
                                </div> -->
                            </div>
                             <div class="profile_img">  
                                <a href=""><img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Phone_Resource, 'smartphone/images/profile_img40x40.jpg')}" alt="" />   </a>
                             </div>     
                             <div class="clear"></div>          
                        </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap"  data-role="content" data-theme="b">
    <div class="main">


                        <apex:form >
                        <apex:actionFunction action="{!saves}" name="save"/>
                         <div class="headDiv">
                             <h3>Opportunity</h3>
                         </div>

                        <div class="tableborder">                        
                         <table class="tableCss">      
                              <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.FieldSets.Opp_field_set}" var="f"> 
                                <tr class="trCss">
                                    <td class="tdCss">  
                                         <apex:outputText value="{!f.Label}" styleClass="label"  /></td>
                                    <td class="tdCss"> 
                                         <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity[f]}" required="{!OR(f.DBRequired, f.required)}"  />  </td>
                                </tr>      
                              </apex:repeat>
                              <tr class="trCss">
                                   <td class="tdCss"></td>
                                   <td class="tdCss"></td>
                               </tr>
                               <tr class="trCss">
                                   <td class="tdCss"></td>
                                   <td class="tdCss">
                                       <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" 
                                        onclick="save()">Save</a>
                                       </td>
                               </tr>
                         </table>



                        </div>                         
                    </apex:form>




        </div>
    </div>
     <div Class= "spacer">
    </div>
      <div data-role="footer"  data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="navbar">

        <ul>
                                <li><a rel="external" href="/apex/Lead " data-role="button" data-icon="grid" >New Deal<br/></a></li>
                                <li><a rel="external"  href="/apex/Lead_List " data-role="button" data-icon="edit" >My Deals<br/></a></li>
                                <li><a rel="external"  href="/apex/opportunity_list " data-role="button" data-icon="action" >Edit Opportunities</a></li>

                            </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /footer -->
</body> 

</apex:page>
```

Here is the generated html source from firebug

```
    <form id="j_id0:j_id5" name="j_id0:j_id5" method="post" action="https://c.na15.visual.force.com/apex/Opportunity?id=006i000000HXXPyAAP" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input name="j_id0:j_id5" value="j_id0:j_id5" type="hidden">

<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">function dpf(f) {var adp = f.adp;if (adp != null) {for (var i = 0;i < adp.length;i++) {adp[i].parentNode.removeChild(adp[i]);}}};function apf(f, pvp) {var adp = new Array();f.adp = adp;var ps = pvp.split(',');for (var i = 0,ii = 0;i < ps.length;i++,ii++) {var p = document.createElement("input");p.type = "hidden";p.name = ps[i];p.value = ps[i + 1];f.appendChild(p);adp[ii] = p;i += 1;}};function jsfcljs(f, pvp, t) {apf(f, pvp);var ft = f.target;if (t) {f.target = t;}f.submit();f.target = ft;dpf(f);};</script>
<script>function save(){ SfdcApp.Visualforce.VSManager.vfPrepareForms(["j_id0:j_id5"]); if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.forms['j_id0:j_id5'],'j_id0:j_id5:j_id6,j_id0:j_id5:j_id6','');}return false }</script>
                         <div class="headDiv">
                             <h3>Opportunity</h3>
                         </div>

                        <div class="tableborder">                        
                         <table class="tableCss"> 
                                <tbody><tr class="trCss">
                                    <td class="tdCss"><span class="label">Name</span></td>
                                    <td class="tdCss"><script> if(!window.sfdcPage){window.sfdcPage = new ApexDetailPage();}
UserContext.initialize({"networkId":"","locale":"en_US","labelLastModified":"1395638224000","isDefaultNetwork":true,"today":"4/11/2014 1:51 AM","timeFormat":"h:mm a","userPreferences":[{"index":112,"name":"HideInlineEditSplash","value":false},{"index":114,"name":"OverrideTaskSendNotification","value":false},{"index":115,"name":"DefaultTaskSendNotification","value":false},{"index":119,"name":"HideUserLayoutStdFieldInfo","value":false},{"index":116,"name":"HideRPPWarning","value":false},{"index":87,"name":"HideInlineSchedulingSplash","value":false},{"index":88,"name":"HideCRUCNotification","value":false},{"index":89,"name":"HideNewPLESplash","value":false},{"index":90,"name":"HideNewPLEWarnIE6","value":false},{"index":122,"name":"HideOverrideSharingMessage","value":false},{"index":91,"name":"HideProfileILEWarn","value":false},{"index":93,"name":"HideProfileElvVideo","value":false},{"index":97,"name":"ShowPicklistEditSplash","value":false},{"index":92,"name":"HideDataCategorySplash","value":false},{"index":128,"name":"ShowDealView","value":false},{"index":129,"name":"HideDealViewGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":132,"name":"HideKnowledgeFirstTimeSetupMsg","value":false},{"index":104,"name":"DefaultOffEntityPermsMsg","value":false},{"index":135,"name":"HideNewCsnSplash","value":false},{"index":101,"name":"HideBrowserWarning","value":false},{"index":139,"name":"HideDashboardBuilderGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":140,"name":"HideSchedulingGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":180,"name":"HideReportBuilderGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":183,"name":"HideAssociationQueueCallout","value":false},{"index":194,"name":"HideQTEBanner","value":false},{"index":193,"name":"HideChatterOnboardingSplash","value":false},{"index":195,"name":"HideSecondChatterOnboardingSplash","value":false},{"index":270,"name":"HideIDEGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":282,"name":"HideQueryToolGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":196,"name":"HideCSIGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":271,"name":"HideFewmetGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":272,"name":"HideEditorGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":205,"name":"HideApexTestGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":206,"name":"HideSetupProfileHeaderTour","value":false},{"index":207,"name":"HideSetupProfileObjectsAndTabsTour","value":false},{"index":213,"name":"DefaultOffArticleTypeEntityPermMsg","value":false},{"index":214,"name":"HideSelfInfluenceGetStarted","value":false},{"index":215,"name":"HideOtherInfluenceGetStarted","value":false},{"index":216,"name":"HideFeedToggleGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":268,"name":"ShowChatterTab178GuidedTour","value":false},{"index":275,"name":"HidePeopleTabDeprecationMsg","value":false},{"index":276,"name":"HideGroupTabDeprecationMsg","value":false},{"index":222,"name":"TouchExternalLinkReminderSuppression","value":false},{"index":224,"name":"HideUnifiedSearchGuidedTour","value":true},{"index":226,"name":"ShowDevContextMenu","value":true},{"index":227,"name":"HideWhatRecommenderForActivityQueues","value":false},{"index":228,"name":"HideLiveAgentFirstTimeSetupMsg","value":false},{"index":232,"name":"HideGroupAllowsGuestsMsgOnMemberWidget","value":false},{"index":233,"name":"HideGroupAllowsGuestsMsg","value":false},{"index":234,"name":"HideWhatAreGuestsMsg","value":false},{"index":235,"name":"HideNowAllowGuestsMsg","value":false},{"index":236,"name":"HideSocialAccountsAndContactsGuidedTour","value":true},{"index":237,"name":"HideAnalyticsHomeGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":238,"name":"ShowQuickCreateGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":245,"name":"HideFilePageGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":250,"name":"HideForecastingGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":242,"name":"TouchHideOptoutHover","value":false},{"index":251,"name":"HideBucketFieldGuide","value":false},{"index":263,"name":"HideSmartSearchCallOut","value":false},{"index":265,"name":"HideSocialProfilesKloutSplashScreen","value":false},{"index":273,"name":"ShowForecastingQuotaAttainment","value":false},{"index":280,"name":"HideForecastingQuotaColumn","value":false},{"index":301,"name":"HideManyWhoGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":284,"name":"HideExternalSharingModelGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":298,"name":"HideFileSyncBannerMsg","value":false},{"index":299,"name":"HideTestConsoleGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":300,"name":"HideNetworkSetupOverlayGettingStarted","value":false},{"index":302,"name":"HideManyWhoInlineEditTip","value":false},{"index":303,"name":"HideSetupV2WelcomeMessage","value":false},{"index":312,"name":"ForecastingShowQuantity","value":false},{"index":313,"name":"HideDataImporterIntroMsg","value":false},{"index":314,"name":"HideEnvironmentHubLightbox","value":false},{"index":316,"name":"HideSetupV2GuidedTour","value":true},{"index":317,"name":"HideFileSyncMobileDownloadDialog","value":false},{"index":318,"name":"HideHelpBannerQuickActionList","value":false},{"index":321,"name":"HideCustomEntityQuickActionCallout","value":true},{"index":322,"name":"HideEnhancedProfileHelpBubble","value":false},{"index":328,"name":"ForecastingHideZeroRows","value":false},{"index":330,"name":"HideEmbeddedComponentsFeatureCallout","value":true},{"index":340,"name":"HideS1BrowserUI","value":false}],"orgPreferences":[{"index":257,"name":"TabOrganizer","value":true}],"startOfWeek":"1","isAccessibleMode":false,"ampm":["AM","PM"],"renderMode":"RETRO","userId":"005i0000002PN6e","dateTimeFormat":"M/d/yyyy h:mm a","dateFormat":"M/d/yyyy","uiSkin":"Theme3","language":"en_US","siteUrlPrefix":""});
</script><div class="requiredInput"><div class="requiredBlock"></div><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input id="j_id0:j_id5:j_id8:0:j_id12" maxlength="120" name="j_id0:j_id5:j_id8:0:j_id12" required="required" size="20" value="Opp Test" type="text"></div></div>  </td>
                                </tr> 
                                <tr class="trCss">
                                    <td class="tdCss"><span class="label">Close Date</span></td>
                                    <td class="tdCss"><div class="requiredInput"><div class="requiredBlock"></div><span class="dateInput dateOnlyInput"><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input id="j_id0:j_id5:j_id8:1:j_id12" name="j_id0:j_id5:j_id8:1:j_id12" onfocus="DatePicker.pickDate(true, 'j_id0:j_id5:j_id8:1:j_id12', false);" required="required" size="12" value="4/2/2014" type="text"></div><span class="dateFormat">[&nbsp;<a rel="external" class="ui-link" href="javascript:DatePicker.insertDate('4/11/2014', 'j_id0:j_id5:j_id8:1:j_id12', true);">4/11/2014</a>&nbsp;]</span></span></div>  </td>
                                </tr> 
                                <tr class="trCss">
                                    <td class="tdCss"><span class="label">Stage</span></td>
                                    <td class="tdCss"><div class="requiredInput"><div class="requiredBlock"></div><div class="ui-select"><div class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow" id="j_id0:j_id5:j_id8:2:j_id12-button"><span>Prospecting</span><select id="j_id0:j_id5:j_id8:2:j_id12" name="j_id0:j_id5:j_id8:2:j_id12" required="required"><option value="">--None--</option><option value="Prospecting" selected="selected">Prospecting</option>
<option value="Qualification">Qualification</option>
<option value="Needs Analysis">Needs Analysis</option>
<option value="Value Proposition">Value Proposition</option>
<option value="Id. Decision Makers">Id. Decision Makers</option>
<option value="Perception Analysis">Perception Analysis</option>
<option value="Proposal/Price Quote">Proposal/Price Quote</option>
<option value="Negotiation/Review">Negotiation/Review</option>
<option value="Closed Won">Closed Won</option>
<option value="Closed Lost">Closed Lost</option>
</select></div></div></div>  </td>
                                </tr> 
                                <tr class="trCss">
                                    <td class="tdCss"><span class="label">Amount</span></td>
                                    <td class="tdCss"><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input id="j_id0:j_id5:j_id8:3:j_id12" name="j_id0:j_id5:j_id8:3:j_id12" size="20" value="1,000.00" type="text"></div>  </td>
                                </tr> 
                                <tr class="trCss">
                                    <td class="tdCss"><span class="label">Reason for Update</span></td>
                                    <td class="tdCss"><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input id="j_id0:j_id5:j_id8:4:j_id12" maxlength="255" name="j_id0:j_id5:j_id8:4:j_id12" size="20" value="updated stage" type="text"></div>  </td>
                                </tr>
                              <tr class="trCss">
                                   <td class="tdCss"></td>
                                   <td class="tdCss"></td>
                               </tr>
                               <tr class="trCss">
                                   <td class="tdCss"></td>
                                   <td class="tdCss">
                                       <a rel="external" role="button" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all" data-inline="true" data-role="button" href="#" onclick="save()">Save</a>
                                       </td>
                               </tr>
                         </tbody></table>



                        </div><div id="j_id0:j_id5:j_id16"></div>
</form><span id="ajax-view-state-page-container" style="display: none"><span id="ajax-view-state" style="display: none"><input id="com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewState" name="com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewState" value="i: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" type="hidden"><input id="com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateVersion" name="com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateVersion" value="201404012207250934" type="hidden"><input id="com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateMAC" name="com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateMAC" value="AMY2pUIEpE6iPLSta8jmM34lON3b" type="hidden"><input id="com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateCSRF" name="com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateCSRF" value="IvbCaUHN7lnlENBt0bQCWUY7u4YgZzmq911UgvJfwMXJ98EUzcgjnjJCvtwRbpQW3cIz2wKj4vwRUirZAuDnbJzygYf5mjow7PCzz8yj_fhUQqv7cTfEEiSQER3BkYmnsnbM1ePpHi51gRAoqFnBM2KZsWs=" type="hidden"></span></span>
```

Comment: It is impossible to answer this without seeing your code. There are so many reasons this could be happening. Please post your page and controller.

Comment: there is no styling in the code other than the apex:inputfield for opp's closedate. All the styling is picked up from jquerymobile's stylesheet

Comment: Please post your code anyway, so we can help you.

Comment: Added the full chunk of code